# flutter ios app not working in real device

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, xcode8

Developing a `Flutter` app in the `XCode`. Testing the iOS not having any error and working perfectly in iOS simulator but in my real device it's not running, it's just showing a white screen and exiting. Below is the error getting, I have embedded needed framework option in embeded&sign the pod file framework automatically coming in the framework option although I am not using it

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x10492b5dc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
0x10492b5e0 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x10492b5e4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x10492b600               ; <+36>
0x10492b5e8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x10492b5ec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
0x10492b5f0 <+20>: bl     0x104929be8               ; cerror_nocancel
0x10492b5f4 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
0x10492b5f8 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
0x10492b5fc <+32>: ret    
0x10492b600 <+36>: ret    


dyld`_dyld_start:
0x1048e1000 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
0x1048e1004 <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
0x1048e1008 <+8>:   mov    x0, #0x0
x1048e100c <+12>:  mov    x1, #0x0
0x1048e1010 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x1048e1014 <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
0x1048e1018 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
0x1048e101c <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
0x1048e1020 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #0x8]
0x1048e1024 <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
0x1048e1028 <+40>:  adrp   x3, -1
0x1048e102c <+44>:  add    x3, x3, #0x0              ; =0x0 
0x1048e1030 <+48>:  mov    x4, sp
0x1048e1034 <+52>:  bl     0x107c                    ; 
dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded 
const*, unsigned long*)
->  0x1048e1038 <+56>:  mov    x16, x0
0x1048e103c <+60>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
0x1048e1040 <+64>:  cmp    x1, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
0x1048e1044 <+68>:  b.ne   0x1050                    ; <+80>
0x1048e1048 <+72>:  add    sp, x28, #0x8             ; =0x8 
0x1048e104c <+76>:  br     x16
0x1048e1050 <+80>:  mov    x30, x1
0x1048e1054 <+84>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #0x8]
0x1048e1058 <+88>:  add    x1, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
0x1048e105c <+92>:  add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
0x1048e1060 <+96>:  add    x2, x2, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x1048e1064 <+100>: mov    x3, x2
0x1048e1068 <+104>: ldr    x4, [x3]
0x1048e106c <+108>: add    x3, x3, #0x8              ; =0x8 
0x1048e1070 <+112>: cmp    x4, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
0x1048e1074 <+116>: b.ne   0x1068                    ; <+104>
0x1048e1078 <+120>: br     x16

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter
 Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
 AB462019D735/Runner.app/Runner
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
 AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for 
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for ' 
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for 
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for 
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
   AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for 
  '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
   AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/151818E7-BA53-4243-9C43- 
   AB462019D735/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Comment: do you use scenes?

Comment: Since I am developing using flutter I am not sure about it

Comment: I created a test flutter app.that also not working